# Apron sink available for or able to fit a regular 30" base?

Tags: kitchens

Ordered a basic 30" base and now would like to have an apron sink. Is there one out there that will fit or is there a way one can be 'coaxed' to fit.

Answer (score 1):

Usually cabinets for apron sinks (farm sink) have a cabinet sized for the sink. Cabinet doors are shorter, for example. I would not expect any modifications on a standard sink base, or any other standard base cabinet would do what you need.